# What is a Fermi arc?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, semiconductor-physics, superconductivity, weyl-semimetal

What is meant with a [Fermi arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_arc) in the context of Weyl semimetals?

Is this the just a one-dimensional Fermi surface? For example, in electron-doped graphene, the Fermi surface consists of 2 disjoint circles. Can you then say that in this system, the Fermi arc encloses the two Dirac points?

Comment: The Fermi surface of a 2D system is typically a closed contour that encloses a region in momentum space. However, in some cases, the contour is not closed. Such a Fermi surface is known as a Fermi arc. See DOI:10.1126/science.1248783 for some experimental results about Fermi arcs in the cuprates.